# Magento 2.2 2: bin/magento commands not working

Tags: magento2.2.2

I'm getting this error:

```
    Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /home/hgfvhx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:384
Stack trace:
#0 /home/hgfvhx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<?xml version="...')
#1 /home/hgfvhx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Config/Reader/Dom.php(70): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<?xml version="...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, 'xsi:type', NULL)
#2 /home/hgfvhx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(149): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom->_createConfigMerger('Magento\\Framewo...', '<?xml version="...')
#3 /home/hgfvhx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(130): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator))
#4 /home/hgfvhx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(275): Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\File in /home/hgfvhx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 384
```

PHP extensions:-

xmlreader:enabled

xmlrpc: enabled

xsl: enabled

dom: enabled

what the problem take all day searching no solutions worked :/.

Answer (score 0):

Package **php-dom** is a virtual package.

Install the php-dom module on your system:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

If you are using 5.6 versions then go with this way:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml
```

And restart your server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I'm in shared hosting I can't install anything and also can't restart apache. +  php-xml is enabled and dom enabled as I mentioned above

Comment: @MohamedElkashef - Maybe issue occurs due to php version,  have you discussed this matter with server team?

Comment: I already contacted them with chat they tried to help but didn't solve anything then they told me. that I need to call the technical teams.